# How to show that the sequence of Cauchy in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am reading a proof in [Gradient of Sobolev function on level sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998308/gradient-of-sobolev-function-on-level-sets).

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be open and pick $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ where $p\geq 1$. Consider
$$\varphi_\varepsilon(t) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if } t \le 0, \\ \frac{t^2}{2\,\varepsilon} & \text{if } 0 < t \le \varepsilon, \\ t - \frac\varepsilon2 & \text{if } \varepsilon < t.\end{cases}$$
and define $u_{\varepsilon}:=\varphi_{\varepsilon}\circ u$. Then we know that $u_{\varepsilon}:=\varphi_{\varepsilon}\circ u$ by the composition rule in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. In order to show that this $u_{\varepsilon}$ has a limit in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, I want to show that the sequence $\{\tilde{u}_{n}\}$ is Cauchy for $\tilde{u}_n:=u_{\frac{1}{n}}$.

I thought it should be trivial but then failed to prove it anyway. To be more precise, I do not know how to evaluate both
$$\|u_{\frac{1}{m}}-u_{\frac{1}{n}}\|_{L^p}\quad\text{and}\quad\|\nabla u_{\frac{1}{m}}-\nabla u_{\frac{1}{m}}\|_{L^p}$$
The main difficulty is that the measure of $\{x\in\Omega:u(x)>\frac{1}{m}\}$ and $\{x\in\Omega:0\leq u(x)\leq\frac{1}{m}\}$ can both be infinite.

Comment: It might be easier to prove convergence by dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: $|\nabla u_\epsilon| \le |\nabla u|$ almost everywhere (by chain rule).

Comment: @daw You are right! Thank you! I got something wrong in my last comment!